# Использовать подгружаемые библиотеки в дочерних классах

Tags: ооп, классы, php, объекты

Здравствуйте!
Есть основной контроллер(О.К).

```
Class Controller
{      
  function __construct()
  {
   /////
  }
}
```

А есть классы который подгружаются в систему автоматически. 
Таким способом

```
$controller = new Controller;
$Controller->counter = new counter;
```

После чего в (О.К) класс counter доступен так

```
$this->counter->method();
```

Но если наследовать этот класс, и опять использовать этот метод.

То выдается ошибка о не существующем объекте и методе.

**Вопрос:** как сделать что бы можно было использовать подгружаемые библиотеки в дочерних классах? Так

**$this->библиотека->Ее метод();**

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Приведи полный текст примера, который вызывает ошибку. По обрывкам непонятно.

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev

       Class index extends Controller
    {

     function index()
     {
       //В наследуемом классе ошибка, а в родительском это нормально работает
       $this->load->view("header");
     }

    }

Выдает

    Notice: Undefined property: index::$load in /var/www/html/app/controller/index.php on line 8

    Fatal error: Call to a member function view() on a non-object in /var/www/html/app/controller/index.php on line 8

Comment: Всё равно пример неполный. Отредактируй свой вопрос, вставь в него все фрагменты: как ты родительский класс определил, как дочерний, как ты создаёшь сущности этих классов. Сейчас это каша из строчек кода.

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev. Если внимательно посмотреть то видно где определяются классы. Даже в отдельном блоке.

    $controller = new Controller;
    $Controller->counter = new counter;//counter просто отдельный класс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае вам подойдет паттерн Registry. Ничего толкового о нем в интернете не нашел, но на Хабре [вот он упоминается](http://habrahabr.ru/post/31270/). Также этот паттерн очень хорошо реализован в [Опенкарте](http://myopencart.com/).

Comment: Не совсем то, мне нужно обращение к элементу через объект, а не массив.

Comment: @alex159, паттерн Registry подразумевает обращение через объект, а не массив. 

$this->db->query($sql);

$this->image->resize($image);

Comment: @mountpoint. В той статье через массив. 
Можете хотя бы подсказать логику реализации данной задачи?

Comment: @alex159, накалякаю в ideone и постараюсь полностью раскрыть суть паттерна